# A tree $T$ has at least $2$ leaves if it has at least one edge

Tags: graph-theory

> Suppose that $T$ is a tree with $E(T)\geq 1$ edges. Prove that $T$ has at least $2$ leaves.

So, this is the set up of my proof.

We induct on the number $E(T)$ of edges of $T$.

**Base case:** If $T$ has exactly one edge, this edge must have two leaves, one at each end. Thus, $T$ has 2 leaves.

**Inductive Step:** Suppose that there exists $k\geq1$ such that whenever $T'$ is a tree with $1\leq E(T')\leq k$ then $E(T')$ has at least two leaves. Let $T$ be a tree with $E(T)=k+1$ edges. We will show that $T$ has at least two leaves.

I could use some help in proving the inductive step. I know I want to divide it into two cases, one where $T'$ is connected, and one where it's disconnected. And somehow apply the inductive step, but I am not sure exactly how.

Comment: You could prove this by induction but it's a little easier to do it directly by looking at the path of longest length in $T$.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: see my hint in the awnsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $T$ be a non trivial tree, $T$ has many paths choose the one that is longest $u-v$ path say $P$. The length of this path is certainly more than 1 since there is at least one edge.  Why are $u$ and $v$ necessarily leaves or vertices with degree 1?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to think about the number of edges (or the sum of the degrees, which is twice the number of edges). If there are $n$ vertices and at most one leaf $v_\ell$, then the sum of degrees is at least $$\sum_{v \in V}\deg v = \deg v_\ell + \sum_{v \ne v_\ell} \deg v \ge 1 + \sum_{v \ne v_\ell} 2 = 1 + 2(n-1) = 2n-1.$$ But there are $n-1$ edges, so the sum of degrees should be $2n-2$, and this is a contradiction.

Induction is normally a great thing to try on trees, but it's not a great idea here because of how induction on trees usually works. The idea is that after you check the base case, you say something like:

"Assume the statement holds for all trees with $n$ vertices. Let $T$ be a tree with $n+1$ vertices, and let $v$ be a leaf of $T$. Then $T-\{v\}$ is a tree with $n$ vertices, and therefore by the induction hypothesis..."

This is kind of awkward when what we're trying to prove is that trees have leaves. On the other hand, if you're okay assuming that all trees have at least *one* leaf, you could use this framework to prove that all trees of size $n\ge 2$ have at least two leaves.